# Is there any way to edit my character's voice in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

I love playing as Gaige, but her screams of pain are really disturbing.

EDIT: I'm on the PC.

Comment: Definitely not if you're playing on a console.  It's more likely you can if you're playing on PC, but I wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: You could always mute the sound.  It's not ideal, but it does prevent the annoyance of the screams.  It probably introduces a whole new layer of annoyance, though.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Yeah, was considering that but I'm hoping to keep the sound. I've edited the question to provide information on my platform.

Comment: If you're not concerned about story progress, you can play up to the quest where you (SPOILERS!) take Jack's voice module and don't progress further in the story. Although, this has a side-effect of you sounding like Jack now, which may be a wholly different bag of disturbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Audio menu, try to turn off "Player Callouts". It will turn off all those little yapping and screaming (if I'm not mistaken)